# Hydrocarbons of Titan: Potential Applications

Tags: materials, titan, saturn, chemistry

Imagine in the future that some space agency or corporation has deployed a manned mission to Saturn's moon Titan with the intent of collecting samples of its hydrocarbons. This is to be accomplished by the deployment of some automated collectors, robots remotely guided by technicians in orbit aboard the main craft. Upon retrieving HC samples from various local features (hills, lakes, plains, etc.), the ship turns tail and rockets back to Earth, where the samples will be sent to laboratories for further study.

I personally know little about the complex chemistry of this amazing moon, so I would like to find out from this community what useful applications may result if we could get our hands on industrially-significant amounts of these materials from Titan. Do they differ from any hydrocarbons commonly found on Earth, and if so do they offer any industrial/economic/scientific benefits worth the cost of such a distant voyage?

Comment: Under current economics - that's an important proviso - it will almost certainly be a better deal to spend the energy budget manufacturing any such hydrocarbons on Earth. But man - what an incredible journey that would be...I can't imagine there wouldn't be something of value to discover.

Comment: Here are some other questions [tagged with titan and chemistry](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titan+chemistry)

Comment: Under current economics and launch costs no hydrocarbon would pay off. Even if we consider all known organic matter only some pharmaceutical and recreational drugs would payoff. But there is almost 0% chance that we could find them on Titan. As far of some elements id doubt that even gold, rhodium and platinum would payoff. But diamonds, rare gemstones, plutonium, tritium and He3 if abound on Titan definitely would be worth a try.